# How to assign value to a class that inherits List(Of T) using Me or MyClass

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I'm relatively new to VB.Net. I have a class that reads xml files and loads the file into a List. The class basically inherits the List(Of T) so I can pass any type of class to it.
Here is my class code

```
Public Class ListFromXML(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of T)

Sub New(FileName As String, xmlRoot As String)

    Dim deserialized As List(Of T) = Nothing
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of T)), New XmlRootAttribute(xmlRoot))
    Using file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & FileName)
        deserialized = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(file), List(Of T))
        For Each item As T In deserialized
            Me.Add(item)
        Next
    End Using

End Sub
End Class
```

I don't want to loop to add the values to the class (Me.Add(item))

My question is: is there is a way to assign the deserialized  list directly to my class like this:

```
    Me= deserialized  
    'or
    MyClass= deserialized
```

Any other suggestions on my code would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the method was not the ctor and was shared, you could return a new instance of  `ListFromXML`; if you used/implemented a List<T> rather than inherited from it, you could use AddRange

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix I was able to use AddRange and skip the loop so this solved my issue. But my question is more conceptual now. I just need to know how a value can be assigned directly to the 'List' once the class is instantiated.